# Does the updates on the global index require locks on the corresponding entries?

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a question regarding the global index.

By using the *Oracle partitioning*, we can improve *the transaction throughputs*, however, if the access to the index incurs large overhead, the performance may degrade

Say that a transaction inserts 100 rows to a table with a global index.
The transaction can access an arbitrarily number of cluster machines in order to update the global index entries.
I wonder what exactly happens when the transaction updates the global index entries.

Does the transaction require locks on the corresponding entries? 
(i.e. 2PC)

I found that Oracle supports *asynchronous maintenance* for `DROP`, `TRUNCATE` operations.

Comment: An articles says the Oracle distributed databases use 2PC for transactions.
https://blogs.oracle.com/db/oracle-support-master-note-for-troubleshooting-managed-distributed-transactions-doc-id-1006641

Comment: Any record attributes in the index are also in the table so any operation on the indexed values would also need to change the table values, and require a lock in both places. An index restructure (eg move/rebuild ) would not.

Comment: @GaryMyers thanks, is there any Official documentation from Oracle on this locking behavior?

Comment: The concepts manual is probably the best place to start 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/consist.htm#CNCPT1364